# Hair particles render not same as 3dView(Eevee)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, hair

Hair particle renders are not same as in 3dView(Eevee).

Hair is using `Principle Bsdf shader` and  camera is set to `Orthographic`.

`Force and turbulence fields` are applied to it.

How to resolve this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Render steps are higher than the Viewport Stand Steps.
Change that and that's it

[image]